# How to comply with the Google AdSense policy that ads should not be placed on auto-generated pages?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I have a website `post4city.com`. Sent an application for Google AdSense. It was rejected with message.

> Site does not comply with Google policies: We're unable to approve your AdSense application at this time because your site does not comply with the Google AdSense program policies
>
> Tips to improve.
>
> Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
>   Your site should also provide a good user experience through clear navigation and organization. Users should be able to easily click through your pages and find the information they’re seeking.

Before I resubmit I need suggestions about what changes I should be making? The site is in Joomla 2.5 - Adsmanager.

Answer (score 2):

I clicked through to the products that you have for sale.  Every single one has a description that is extremely spammy.  They are often little more than lists of keywords.  For example, here is a copy and paste:

> New Lunched Blackberry Q10 & Blackberry Porsche design p9981 with
>   special pins codes all original Unlocked with 18 Month international
>
> - Apple iPhone 5s 16GB
> - Apple iPhone 5s 32GB
> - Apple iPhone 5s 64GB
> - iPhone 5 Gold 24karat
> - Apple iPhone 5 64GB
> - Samsung GALAXY S 4

It uses "Porche", "Blackberry", "iPhone", and "Samsung" all in one description.  The sentences make almost no sense.  Is it any wonder a Google AdSense reviewer might think the pages on your website are machine generated?

To comply with this policy you would need to clean up the pages on your site.  Especially the ones that are featured on the front of the home page.